# IGMP/Multicast routing in Linux

Tags: multicast, igmp

I need to route IGMP/Multicast traffic across two networks.  I have a Linux box with two NICs, one public, one private.  Need devices on the private network to flow to public.  I'm pretty certain I have iptables set up right, been trying to do this with IGMPProxy.  It doesn't work on PCs on provate, but from the Linux server I can ping 224.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

you can route multicast traffic on Linux using mrouted. It's quite old but still working... :-)

Answer (score 0):

IGMP works only in a link-local scope and you should not try to route it with iptables.

You can setup some IGMP routing daemon like the one provided by [Xorp.org](http://www.xorp.org/) or you can discard the IGMP information (if your setup is static) and use use [smcroute](http://www.cschill.de/smcroute/) to manipulate the kernel multicast routing table.